# CSS Grid not centering the top row

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I have an issue with the top row in the following layout. It would not center and just stay on the left part of the two columns.
It need it to be on the center like the bottom part. The one on the bottom works fine at centering itself even though I used the same way via CSS Grid. Please check the image I attached.

```css
#about-container {
  grid-area: first;
}

#ul-first {
  grid-area: second;
}

#ul-second {
  grid-area: third;
}

#ul-third {
  grid-area: fourth;
}

.footer-links {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "first first" 
    "second third" 
    "fourth fourth";
}
```

```html
<section class="footer-links">
  <div class="about-container">
    <div class="about">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, aperiam quaerat? Nam reprehenderit, amet minus illum natus facere accusamus aut voluptatem. Sapiente ipsa praesentium unde, voluptatem assumenda facilis asperiores eum!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="ul-first">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Why Buy From Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Company Policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Financing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="ul-second">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Request a Quote</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get in Touch with Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Book Preventive Maintenance</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="ul-third">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Nissan GT-R</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mitsubishi Lancer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Toyota Corolla Touring</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">McLaren P1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: `#about-container` is not a class which is what you used in your HTML

Comment: Thanks! Did not notice that. I also fixed that now. Still that didn't fix the problem though. After adding margin from one of the answers below, it worked. Still don't understand why it worked without any margin on the third row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is an error in your code : in your CSS, you specify rules for the id : `#about-container` but it doesn't exist in your HTML (it's a class in there).
Second, your code doesn't yield the result you have in your image (it seems you are using the property `text-align:center;` that I can't ssee in the code you share).

To answer your question, you can center the first element by using : `.about { width:50%; margin:0 auto; }`
With your example, it would be (I also correted both errors I pointed out above) :

```css
#about-container {
  grid-area: first;
}

.about {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ul-first {
  grid-area: second;
  text-align: center;
}

#ul-second {
  grid-area: third;
  text-align: center;
}

#ul-third {
  grid-area: fourth;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-links {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "first first" 
    "second third" 
    "fourth fourth";
}
```

```html
<section class="footer-links">
  <div id="about-container">
    <div class="about">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, aperiam quaerat? Nam reprehenderit, amet minus illum natus facere accusamus aut voluptatem. Sapiente ipsa praesentium unde, voluptatem assumenda facilis asperiores eum!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="ul-first">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Why Buy From Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Company Policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Financing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="ul-second">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Request a Quote</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get in Touch with Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Book Preventive Maintenance</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list" id="ul-third">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Nissan GT-R</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mitsubishi Lancer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Toyota Corolla Touring</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">McLaren P1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah everything was in text-align: center. I forgot to add it since this part is for the tablet view, I got the text-align right at the top. Forgot about that. Anyway, adding the .about from your code fixed it for me. But how come in the third row it worked without any problem but on the top I needed to use margin?

Comment: @PMConcepcion the bottom row was aligned by the `text-align:center;` it's lines don't take all the width so it looks centered. The top element is also aligned center but the lines take all the width so it doesn't look centered. Test my example and remove the width and margin on the first element to see what happens. I can't say for your example (the one from the image) as there is code for it that I don't have accesss to.

Comment: I see. Thank you. You're correct, I did forget to add text-align. I added text-align: center on my .about-container and that actually fixed it. The .about is now centered. So it was the .about all along that was not centered, I thought it was the parent element. This was the solution actually, but I'll keep the margin since it made it much better in terms of neatness. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just use this useful trick to center most anything

```css
element {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
#about-container{
    grid-area: first;
}
#ul-first{
    grid-area: second;
}
#ul-second{
    grid-area: third;
}
#ul-third{
    grid-area: fourth;
}
.footer-links{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "first first"
        "second third"
        "fourth fourth";
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="footer-links">
            <div class="about-container">
                <div class="about">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, aperiam quaerat? Nam reprehenderit, amet minus illum natus facere accusamus aut voluptatem. Sapiente ipsa praesentium unde, voluptatem assumenda facilis asperiores eum!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list" id="ul-first">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Why Buy From Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Company Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Financing</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="list" id="ul-second">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Request a Quote</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch with Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book Preventive Maintenance</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="list" id="ul-third">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Nissan GT-R</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mitsubishi Lancer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Toyota Corolla Touring</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">McLaren P1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry was not able to include it in the CSS, but everything had text-align: center on the top part of the code. This is for the media query of 768px so I forgot to add that up.